# Generating random sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, r, rcpp

My goal is to generate a large sparse matrix with majority (~99%) zeros and ones. Ideally, I would be working with 10,000 rows and 10,000,000 columns. Additionally, each column is generated as a sequence of Bernoulli samples with a **column-specific** probability. So far, I've implemented 3 ways to generate the data:

**Function 1**

Creating basic dense matrix of 0/1:

```
spMat_dense <- function(ncols,nrows,col_probs){
  matrix(rbinom(nrows*ncols,1,col_probs),
         ncol=ncols,byrow=T)
}
```

**Function 2**

Using `Rcpp`:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

using namespace std;
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::sp_mat spMat_cpp(const int& ncols, const int& nrows, const NumericVector& col_probs){

  IntegerVector binom_draws = no_init(nrows);
  IntegerVector row_pos;
  IntegerVector col_pos;
  int nz_counter=0;

  //Generate (row,cell)-coordinates of non-zero values
  for(int j=0; j<ncols; ++j){
    binom_draws = rbinom(nrows,1,col_probs[j]);
    for(int i=0; i<nrows; ++i){
      if(binom_draws[i]==1){ 
        row_pos.push_back(i);
        col_pos.push_back(j);
        nz_counter += 1;
      }
    }
  }

  //Create a 2 x N matrix - indicates row/col positions for N non-zero entries
  arma::umat loc_mat(2,nz_counter);

  for(int i=0;i<nz_counter; ++i){
    loc_mat(0,i) = row_pos[i];
    loc_mat(1,i) = col_pos[i];
  }

  IntegerVector x_tmp = rep(1,nz_counter);
  arma::colvec x = Rcpp::as<arma::colvec>(x_tmp);

  //sparse matrix constructor
  arma::sp_mat out(loc_mat,x);
  return out;
}
```

**Function 3**

Using `dgCMatrix` construction in `Matrix` package:

```
spMat_dgC <- function(ncols,nrows,col_probs){
  #Credit to Andrew Guster (https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348978/4321711)
  require(Matrix)
  mat <- Matrix(0, nrows, ncols, sparse = TRUE)  #blank matrix for template
  i <- vector(mode = "list", length = ncols)     #each element of i contains the '1' rows
  p <- rep(0, ncols)                             #p will be cumsum no of 1s by column
  for(r in 1:nrows){
    row <- rbinom(ncols, 1, col_probs)            #random row
    p <- p + row                                 #add to column identifier
    if(any(row == 1)){
      for (j in which(row == 1)){
        i[[j]] <- c(i[[j]], r-1)                 #append row identifier
      }
    }
  }
  p <- c(0, cumsum(p))                           #this is the format required
  i <- unlist(i)
  x <- rep(1, length(i))
  mat@i <- as.integer(i)
  mat@p <- as.integer(p)
  mat@x <- x
  return(mat)
}
```

**Benchmarking**

```
ncols = 100000
nrows = 1000
col_probs = runif(ncols, 0.001, 0.002)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(generate_SpMat1(ncols=ncols,nrows=nrows,col_probs=col_probs),
                               generate_SpMat2(ncols=ncols,nrows=nrows,col_probs = col_probs),
                               generate_spMat(ncols=ncols,nrows=nrows,col_probs=col_probs),
                               times=5L)

Unit: seconds
                                                          expr
      spMat_dense(ncols = ncols, nrows = nrows, col_probs = col_probs)
 spMat_cpp(ncols = ncols, nrows = nrows, col_probs = col_probs)
     spMat_dgC(ncols = ncols, nrows = nrows, col_probs = col_probs)
       min        lq      mean   median        uq       max neval
  6.527836  6.673515  7.260482  7.13241  7.813596  8.155053     5
 56.726238 57.038976 57.841693 57.24435 58.325564 59.873333     5
  6.541939  6.599228  6.938952  6.62452  7.402208  7.526867     5
```

Interestingly, my `Rcpp` code is not as optimal as I thought it would be. I'm not entirely sure why it's not as efficient as the basic, dense construction. The advantage however in the `Rcpp` and `dgCMatrix` construction is that they don't create a dense matrix first. The memory used is much less:

```
ncols = 100000
nrows = 1000
col_probs = runif(ncols, 0.001, 0.002)

mat1 <- spMat_dense(ncols=ncols,nrows=nrows,col_probs=col_probs)
mat2 <- spMat_cpp(ncols=ncols,nrows=nrows,col_probs = col_probs)
mat3 <- spMat_dgC(ncols=ncols,nrows=nrows,col_probs=col_probs)

object.size(mat1)
object.size(mat2)
object.size(mat3)

> object.size(mat1)
400000216 bytes
> object.size(mat2)
2199728 bytes
> object.size(mat3)
2205920 bytes
```

**Question**

What is it about my `Rcpp` code that makes it slower than the other two? Is it possible to optimize or is the well-written R code with `dgCMatrix` as good as it gets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems faster in `r`:

```
minem2 <- function(ncols, nrows, col_probs){
  r <- lapply(1:ncols, function(x) {
    p <- col_probs[x]
    i <- sample.int(2L, size = nrows, replace = T, prob = c(1 - p, p))
    which(i == 2L)
  })
  rl <- lengths(r)
  nc <- rep(1:ncols, times = rl) # col indexes
  nr <- unlist(r) # row index
  ddims <- c(nrows, ncols)
  sparseMatrix(i = nr, j = nc, dims = ddims)
}
```

Andrew Guster commented on this approach ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56348978/4321711))

Maybe using this logic `Rcpp` code could be written faster...

Generally, we do not need to generate all values, but just get the indexes where value is 1.